# How to get substring of a local variable in loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a script to get all file names in a directory and also exclude file name end with ***all***.

I've came up with below script but it does not work, could anyone help me?

```
for /R "%SOME_DIRECTORY%" %%f in (*.testcase) do (
    set CURRENT_TESTCASE=%%~nf
    if not %CURRENT_TESTCASE:~-3%==all  (
        echo %%~nf >> "%FILELIST%"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `CURRENT_TESTCASE` variable is evaluated before the loop's body is executed. (That is how the command processor deal with the compound commands that contain parantheses.)

To prevent the variable from being evaluated prematurely you need to enable the [delayed expansion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) of variables locally and change the syntax slightly. Here's how:

```
for /R "%SOME_DIRECTORY%" %%f in (*.testcase) do (
    set CURRENT_TESTCASE=%%~nf
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not !CURRENT_TESTCASE:~-3!==all  (
        echo %%~nf >> "%FILELIST%"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do that *outside* the loop? Or does it work if it's inside too?

Comment: You can enable/disable delayed expansion for any part of your script. It's often desirable to limit the scope of its operation so as to avoid unexpected consuming of `!` where you don't need it.